# How to configure a NVIDIA Gpu to depth=30?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, color-depth

I have a new 4k HDR10 monitor, an NVIDIA gforce 1030 Gpu and Ubuntu 18.04. nvidia-settings reports  depth=24.  How do I configure the Gpu to depth=30?